# typeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'tView' of object '[object Object]' in angular 9.0.4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been using Angular 8, and recently updated to Angular 9. But when I run the project, it showd me this error in console:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'tView' of object '[object Object]'
> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'tView' of object '[object Object]'
> at getOrCreateTComponentView (core.js:7621)
> at createRootComponentView (core.js:18895)
> at

this is my package.json :

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.28",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.4",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.134",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
    "angular2-permission": "^0.1.3",
    "angular2-promise-buttons": "^4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^9.15.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^8.4.1",
    "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.2.7",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.1.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.1.3",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.8",
    "@types/object-path": "^0.11.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2"
}
```

Comment: Github issue - https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using ngrx with ngrx-store-freeze. Most likely you have an action or data model in your store which contains an angular component/template/directive. If you remove `storeFreeze` from your `metaReducers`, you will most likely not see the error anymore.

Nevertheless, you should find out what reducer is adding this component to the store, and find another way to handle this. It's definitely not a good idea to have such objects in your store anyways

Answer (score 16):

This is a problem with NGRX Store and Ivy runtime which began in Angular 9

The problem is best explained here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2109

The current workaround  (16th March 2020) is to disable both

```
strictStateImmutability and strictActionImmutability
```

in your StoreModule metareducers

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]), 
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, 
    { metaReducers, 
        runtimeChecks: { 
            strictStateImmutability: false, 
            strictActionImmutability: false,
        } 
    }
),
```

Of course, this is a workaround and doesn't solve the problem. An issue is currently open with NGRX  https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2404

Comment: Thanks for this, I was headed down the wrong path. Very likely saved my hours of spinning my wheels

Answer (score 0):

I'm just sharing my 2 cents here as I found out that I made a mistake, which lead to kind of the same error. I was doing a mutation inside the selector of ngrx.

My error was:

> Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'

```
export const selectInspections = createSelector(selectInspectionsFeature, (state) =>
    state.inspections.sort((a, b) => (a.dateTimeUpdated > b.dateTimeUpdated ? -1 : 1))
);
```

Solved it by changing it like this:

```
export const selectInspections = createSelector(selectInspectionsFeature, 
(state) =>
    [...state.inspections].sort((a, b) => (a.dateTimeUpdated > b.dateTimeUpdated ? -1 : 1))
);
```

Now I am not modifying the state inside the selector.